# Compare the letters in two words to see if they have any letters in common

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops, boolean

The function wordPass is supposed to take two words/strings as parameters and look for letters that they have in common. If they have letters in common, the function returns True, if not, it returns False.

Here is what I tried:

```vb
Function wordPass(wordleAnswer As String, guess As String) As Boolean

    For i = 1 To Len(wordleAnswer)
        For j = 1 To Len(guess)
            same = False
            If Mid(guess, j, 1) = Mid(wordleAnswer, i, 1) Then
                same = True
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    wordPass = same

End Function
```

Comment: As soon as `same = True` you can exit the function.  Otherwise you're resetting it to False in the next iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can eliminate one loop using `InStr`:

```
Function wordPass(wordleAnswer As String, guess As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(guess)
        If InStr(wordleAnswer, Mid$(guess, i, 1)) > 0 Then
            wordPass = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried testing this but something that should return TRUE is giving me FALSE. For example, wordPass("thump","mummy") is supposed to be TRUE, but it comes out as FALSE.

Comment: @Excelling, oops, forgot the `, 1` in `Mid`, edited.